# Amazon Availability Checker

Tags: python, web-scraping

Im a complete beginner

i would like to change this code, so that i can read the Asins line by line from a CSV file or a text file and get notified when Amazon is out of stock.

I hope someone has an idea

Thank you in advance

**Python script for Amazon product availability checker**

```py
# importing libraries
from lxml import html
import requests
from time import sleep
import time
import schedule
import smtplib

receiver_email_id = "EMAIL_ID_OF_USER"

def check(url):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}

    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    for i in range(20):
        sleep(3)

        doc = html.fromstring(page.content)

        XPATH_AVAILABILITY = '//div[@id ="availability"]//text()'
        RAw_AVAILABILITY = doc.xpath(XPATH_AVAILABILITY)
        AVAILABILITY = ''.join(RAw_AVAILABILITY).strip() if RAw_AVAILABILITY else None
        return AVAILABILITY

def ReadAsin():
    
    Asin = 'B07XCRYSDT'
    url = "http://www.amazon.de/dp/" + Asin
    print("Processing: " + url)
    ans = check(url)
    arr = [
        'Only 1 left in stock.',
        'Only 2 left in stock.',
        'In stock.']
    print(ans)
    if ans in arr:
        # sending email to user if
        # in case product available
        sendemail(ans, Asin)

def job():
    print("Tracking....")
    ReadAsin()


schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.